# Overloaded less then operator does't work in my template sorted linked list

Tags: c++, sorting, pointers, linked-list, operator-overloading

I am implementing a template sorted linked list with sorted insert. I also made the class `Booking`. `Booking` is a base class and derived from it are some bookingtypes. I want to use the linked list to store some `Booking*`s in there. (I have to use pointers here)

**Bookings.h**

```
#ifndef BOOKING_H
#define BOOKING_H
#include <iostream>

class Booking{

private:
  long bookingID;


public:
  Booking(long bookingID);
  long getBookingID();
  bool operator<(Booking& b1);

};

#endif // BOOKING_H
```

**Booking.cpp** (the < operator is being overloaded here)

```
#include "booking.h"

Booking::Booking(long bookingID):bookingID(bookingID){}

long Booking::getBookingID(){
   return bookingID;
}

bool Booking::operator<(Booking &b){
   return this->bookingID < b.getBookingID();
}
```

**node.h**

```
#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class LinkedList;

template <typename T>
class Node {

public:
Node(T data) : data(data),previousNode(nullptr),nextNode(nullptr) {}

Node<T>* GetNextNode() const {
    return nextNode;
}

void SetNextNode(Node<T>* nextNode) {
    this->nextNode = nextNode;
}

Node<T>* GetPreviousNode() const {
    return previousNode;
}

void SetPreviousNode(Node<T>* previousNode) {
    this->previousNode = previousNode;
}

T GetData() const {
    return data;
}

void SetData(T data) {
    this->data = data;
}

private:
T data;
Node<T>* previousNode;
Node<T>* nextNode;
};

#endif  /* NODE_H */
```

**linkedList.h**

```
#ifndef LINKEDLIST_H
#define LINKEDLIST_H
#include "node.h"
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>
#include <booking.h>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class LinkedList {
public:

LinkedList(T data) {
    root = nullptr; // root darf nur bei einer leeren Liste gleich NULL sein
    end = new Node<T>(data);
    cursor = end;
}

bool isAtEnd() {
    return (cursor == end);
};

void step_back() {
    if (cursor && cursor->GetPreviousNode()) {
        cursor = cursor->GetPreviousNode();
    }
}

void advance() {
    if (cursor && cursor->GetNextNode()) {
        cursor = cursor->GetNextNode();        }
};


T getNode() {
    return cursor->GetData();
};

void reset() {
    cursor = root;
};

void sortedInsert(T data) {
    Node<T>* node = new Node<T>(data);
    reset();

    if(root == nullptr){
        root = node;
        node->SetNextNode(end);
        end->SetPreviousNode(node);
        cursor = node;
        root = cursor;
    }else{
        while(!isAtEnd()){
            if((*data<*(cursor->GetData()))){
                node->SetPreviousNode(cursor->GetPreviousNode());
                node->SetNextNode(cursor);
                cursor->GetPreviousNode()->SetNextNode(node);
                cursor->SetPreviousNode(node);
                reset(); //cursor zurück zu listenanfang (root)
                return;
            }
            advance();
        }
        if(!isAtEnd()){
            node->SetPreviousNode(end->GetPreviousNode());
            node->SetNextNode(end);
            end->GetPreviousNode()->SetNextNode(node);
            end->SetPreviousNode(node);
        }
    }
    reset();
}

protected:
  Node<T>* root;
  Node<T>* cursor;
  Node<T>* end;
};
#endif  /* LINKEDLIST_H */
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <linkedList.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <booking.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

// creating a linked list with dummy node at the end.
LinkedList<Booking*> allBookings = LinkedList<Booking*>(new Booking(-1));

// these bookings are in actual some bookingtypes stored in Booking
// for example: Booking* bookingx = new FlightBooking(12);
Booking* booking1 = new Booking(99);
Booking* booking2 = new Booking(11);
Booking* booking3 = new Booking(12);
Booking* booking4 = new Booking(33);
Booking* booking5 = new Booking(5);
Booking* booking6 = new Booking(45);
Booking* booking7 = new Booking(34);

allBookings.sortedInsert(booking1);
allBookings.sortedInsert(booking2);
allBookings.sortedInsert(booking3);
allBookings.sortedInsert(booking4);
allBookings.sortedInsert(booking5);
allBookings.sortedInsert(booking6);
allBookings.sortedInsert(booking7);

return a.exec();
}
```

I am guessing that my `sortedInsert(...)` function doesn't work, because the overloading isn't working like expected. I need help in fixing my code.

Comment: Side note: `bool operator<(Booking& b1);` should be `bool operator<(Booking const & b1) const;`. Nothing about the comparison should require mutating either object. As written, this operator cannot be used if either operand is `const`. (In fact, this could be the problem with your code.)

Comment: Unrelated: save yourself some fuss: `Booking* booking1 = new Booking(99);` and `allBookings.sortedInsert(booking1);` could be replaced with `allBookings.sortedInsert(new Booking(99));`

Comment: How is not not working like you expect? [Edit] the question to include details of the expected behavior and the observed behavior.

Comment: I suggest not having `cursor` be a member. It's difficult to keep track of where it could be changing. Use local variables where sufficient. Also, your constructor is not setting `root` correctly.

Comment: Note: If the problem is entirely with the `operator<`  in `Booking`, write a small program that exercises the operator without requiring the linked list. Less code to have to examine for bugs that way. Always try to isolate the problem. Use [mre] for inspiration.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm the comment of cdhowie fixed my issue with the less then operator. I now have the problem, that my sortedInsert algorithm doesn't work. The compiler doesn't throw me an error. The program just stops... Can you guys spot the problem in the sortedInsert algorithm?

Comment: @cigien the code snippet was provided to us from school. root=nullptr means the list that is created is emty.

Comment: A more intuitive empty when you're using a sentinel node would be  to have `root` and `end` both point at the sentinel node. This allows you to write some of the inserts much more easily as there is only one rule to have to look after. Perhaps the reference material from school was not using a sentinel node.

Comment: But the single argument constructor should create an empty linked list? That seems odd. Maybe you are *supposed* to change that?

Comment: @cigien the argument in the constructor is the "dummy node" representing the end of the linked list. It is not part of the linked list. We were given the task to "templetize" the llinked list. How else should I create/initialize a dummy for the end node when creating a linked list?

Comment: I'm not sure what your constraints are, but usually `nullptr` is used to mark the end of a linked list.